# Integration OpenCV in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I have tried this sample. It show red image

```
Mat img(400,400,CV_8UC3, Scalar(0,0,255)); 
imshow("lalala", img);
waitKey();
```

And this code for opennig webcam it's work:

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat image;
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
    cap.open(0);
    namedWindow("window",1);
    while(1)
    {
        try
        {
            cap>>image;
            imshow("window",image);
        }
        catch (Exception& e)
        {
            const char* err_msg = e.what();
            std::cout << "exception caught: imshow:\n" << err_msg << std::endl;
        }
        waitKey(33);
    }
}
```

But this code, it shows : Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if( argc != 2)
    {
        cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file
    if(! image.data ) // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); // Create a window for display.
    imshow( "Display window", image ); // Show our image inside it.
    waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

would someone help me to find the error where become, i'm really blocked. I think the integration of mine opencv 2.4.9 in visual studio 2010 in windows 8.1 is correct because i follow the steps in official web of opencv, also the path of image is correct too, but i think there is a problem in the code because if the problem is in the installation, any program will work (openig webcam or red image).

I asked this question in other forum an the reply was:

> this is not an opencv problem, you might want to look up, how to
>   handle cmdline params (your program expects to be given the path to an
>   image),    the path to an image is expected.

But it's the first time i work with visual studio and opencv.I don't understand what does it mean.

I thank everyone in advance for your help!

Comment: Command line params  - you should call your program using an image as argument - that is what the other forum told you

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the command line parameters to the program.

**OPTION 1:**

Find the .exe of your compiled project. Depending on your configuration it should be located in the folder "Debug" or "Release".

Open a command prompt in that location and type:

> Exe.exe image.jpg

Exe is the name of the executable file and image is the name of the JPG file that you want to open (it should be located in the same folder as the .exe).

**OPTION 2:**

On the solution explorer (Ctrl+Alt+L if you can't see it) **right click** the name of your project and click on "**properties**".

[image: Properties]

A window named "**Property pages**" should have opened. In "**Configuration Properties**" click on "**Debugging**". You should enter in "**Command Argument**" the name of some JPG image in the directory where the .exe of your project is located.

[image]

Comment: I did it but the same result "Could not open or find the image"

Comment: Imagine your executable file is called "Program.exe", then your folder where the .exe is located should contain at least "Program.exe" and "Image.jpg". So you have to open a command prompt in that folder and type "**Program.exe image.jpg**" without the quotes

Comment: thanx asehu, i tried but nothing changed maybe it's not the error

Comment: Try with this code, the same, make sure that you have a file called "image.jpg" in the same directory as the .exe of the application: [https://pastebin.com/n2Zyvqb1](https://pastebin.com/n2Zyvqb1)